# for-based syntax to skip call to 'iter'

Tags: python

Considering the following iterator:

```
class MyIterator:

  def __iter__(self):
    print("Calling `__iter__`")
    return self

  def __reversed__(self):
    print("Calling `__reversed__`")
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    print("Calling `__next__`")
    raise StopIteration
```

Is there a `for`-based equivalent syntax of the following code:

```
R = reversed(MyIterator())
while True:
  try:
    next(R)
  except StopIteration:
    break
```

which actually prints

```
Calling `__reversed__`
Calling `__next__`
```

`for` syntax seems to always add a call to `iter`, even though the given object already respects the Iterator protocol.

Comment: That's the thing: the way Python checks if an object respects the iterator protocol is to call `iter` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `__iter__` implicitly is intentional; `for` doesn't know if it's been handed an itera*tor* or an itera*ble*, and needs to unconditionally ensure it has an itera*tor*, which it does by invoking `__iter__`. If your object is already an iterator, `__iter__` is supposed to be idempotent, doing *nothing* but returning itself (the body should be nothing but `return self`). There are some tests in existing Python code that detect iterators by testing `iter(x) is x`, and if you violate the rules by doing something other than returning `self` in your custom iterator, you're responsible for the misbehavior.

Point is, what you want to do makes no sense. Either write an iterable (without a `__next__`, and a `__iter__` that returns a new iterator) or write an iterator, but if you write an iterator, you need to obey the rules for iterators.

Just to be clear, the unavoidable order of operations here is:

1. `reversed` invokes `__reversed__`, which should in theory return a new reversed iterator (it's very weird to have it return the *existing*, theoretically forward iterator)
2. `for` invokes `__iter__` implicitly on whatever `reversed` returns to ensure it's an iterator (if `__reversed__` were implemented properly, it would have returned a brand new iterator, but instead, you end up invoking `__iter__` on the same object)
3. `for` then call `__next__` implicitly for each item until `StopIteration` is raised

To fix it, have `__reversed__` return a new reverse iterator, not `self`; the new iterator's `__iter__` will still be invoked, but it won't be the one on the original iterator. Even better, split your implementations; something that's reversible shouldn't be an iterator in the first place. Just make `__iter__` and `__reversed__` both generator functions that produce whatever they should produce, and get rid of `__next__`, to make your class itera*ble* and reversible, but not an itera*tor*.